# How to increase the springMVC json response time

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

In spring controller that has long running process and returns output as json, after certain time the controller returns empty json while it is still processing in server. how to handle this in spring

Comment: This looks like server/deployment issue, there's no inherent timeout in Spring MVC itself. You'll need to include more information about *how* you're deploying the application and whether there's anything suspicious in the logs; is the timeout always happen after the same period of time?

Comment: we have used tomcat container on EC2 instance, we have found no suspicious in the log but the application is running fine in the back end only the response is empty even before server done with the process, we are using @Responsebody with services as Asynchronous(@Async)

Answer (score 0):

While fetching records from database or getting records from spring web services as JSON or XML format sometimes connectionTimeout (**500 I/O error**) or readTimeout error occurs.

Increase service elapsed time / **connection timeout** and **read timeout** in spring mvc by using [HttpComponentsMessageSender](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/transport/http/HttpComponentsMessageSender.html)

Require jar [spring-ws-2.1.3.RELEASE-all.jar](https://app.box.com/s/8ux1k7u3i0uwmxqpc32dwmr90p8xsg4g) add it in `WEB-INF/lib` or add below **Maven** dependency in `pom.xml`

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.ws/spring-ws -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

add below code in **mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender">
    <property name="connectionTimeout" value="600000" />
    <property name="readTimeout" value="600000" />
</bean>
```

**Note:** 600000 means 10 Minutes. If you want to `increase timeout` just multiply

1000 Milliseconds * 60 Seconds * **10 Minutes** = 600000

1000 Milliseconds * 60 Seconds * **30 Minutes** = 1800000